# Slicing a circle in equal segments, Python

Tags: python, geometry, computational-geometry, astronomy

I have a set of close of 10,000 points on the sky. They are plotted using the RA (right ascension) and DEC (declination) on the sky. When plotted, they take the shape of a circle.

[image]

What I would like to do is to ***slice the circle into 8 equal parts*** and remove each part one at a time and do some calculations using the remaining parts.

To do so I came up with this illustration in mind, i.e. slicing them using the arcs.

I know that the equation of the arc is given by:

```
S = r * theta
```

where

```
r --> radius
theta --> angle (in our case 45 degrees)
```

I would somehow like to do this like:

```
slice1 = []
for a,b in zip(ra,dec):
    if a>some value and a<some value and b>some value and b<some value:
        slice1.append(a,b)
```

If they were a square, it becomes really easy, and the above equation can immediately be applied.

So once I have my slice, I can then do a `numpy.where()` to find out the rest of my circle.

**I can easily slice it into four slices by just mentioning the `min(RA),max(RA),min(DEC) and max(DEC)`. One such example when I do it for the first quadrant will give me this:**

```
RA>0.0 and RA<max(RA) DEC>0.0 and DEC<max(DEC)
```

[image]

I don't know how to go about doing this in my case (i.e. into 8 quadrants!!), wherein **I only have the x,y coordinates of my data points!!**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can compute the array of slice numbers directly with with `numpy` operators:

```
sliceno = numpy.int32((pi + numpy.arctan2(Y, X)) * (N / (2*pi)))
```

meaning:

- compute the angle `-pi`...`pi` for each point with `arctan2`
- shift by `pi` to make it a positive interval
- rescale to `0`..`N-1`
- convert to an integer

Comment: I can see that sliceno gives me my 8 quadrants, but can you elucidate further??!!

Comment: @ThePredator: I've edited the answer to avoid bit tricks and working instead with a generic `N` for the number of slices.

Comment: what's X Y?  The center of the circle?  How would I get the points between, say, angle 30 to angle 60?  How to add the array of points?  I don't get this at all

Comment: @johnktejik: `X` and  `Y` are two parallel arrays of x and y values for the points; the coordinates are assumed so that the center of the circle is in `(0, 0)`.

Answer (score 5):

You should probably use [math.atan2](https://docs.python.org/2/library/math.html#math.atan2):

```
angle = math.atan2(dec, ra)
if angle >= n*math.pi/4 and angle < (n+1)*math.pi/4:
    # point is inside slice number n
```

Basically, atan2 returns the angle to the point from the x axis. By dividing it into intervals of pi/4, you get your slices. But beware - `atan2` returns angles between -pi and pi, so you should number your slices from -4 to 3 (or you can add pi to the angle, or convert it in some other way).

EDIT: Modifying your code, it would look like this:

```
slice1 = []
n = 0  #change 0 to desired slice number here (from -4 to 3)
for a,b in zip(ra,dec):
    angle = math.atan2(b,a)
    if angle >= n*math.pi/4 and angle < (n+1)*math.pi/4:
        slice1.append(a,b)
```

Comment: sorry for delayed response, when I do `angle = math.atan2(data_dec_par,data_ra_par)` I get `TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars`.

Comment: I'm guessing that's because `data_dec_par` and `data_ra_par` are lists and I assumed that `ra` and `dec` are numbers. You'll have to loop through points, for example like you did before (`for a,b in zip(ra,dec):` etc.).

Comment: you mean like: `for a,b in zip(ra,dec):` `angle = arctan()` and then I do the `if` statement? Can you explain via an edit if possible?

Comment: Sure, I edited the answer and added a modified version of your code.

Comment: Your answer works, but I find the above answer by 6502 more easier. So I accepted it as the answer.

Comment: No problem, use what's better for you ;)

Answer (score 2):

First, find the quadrant using your formula. The octant can then be determined by comparing `abs(x)` with `abs(y)`.

In the lower octant, `abs(x) >= abs(y)`. The other one has `abs(x) < abs(y)`

Comment: He already knew how to find the quadrants, he wanted to split the circle in 8.

Comment: @SiHa The formula was kind of correct, the explanation was wrong. fixed.

Comment: A nice simple solution. Easy (and, in fact, obvious) once you forget the fact that it is a circle :)

Comment: Can you elucidate a bit further? I am not able to apply this!