# Python, removing similar values from two lists

Tags: python, list, for-loop, list-comprehension

I have two lists, let's call them `list1` and `list2`.

`list1` is the main list which contains all the values of my data.

`list2` contains certain values that have to be removed from `list1`. **(You can say it is sort of like a sublist of `list1`)**

```
len(list1) = 13357
len(list2) = 1751
```

**So to remove values of `list2` from `list1` I do:**

```
new_list = [x for x in list1 if x not in list2]
```

So what **you would expect** is for `new_list` to have a length:

```
len(new_list) = len(list1) - len(list2) = 13357 - 1751 = 11606
```

However my **`new_list` has a length = 11584** !!!

How is this possible????!!!!!

**EDIT:**
I obtained my `list2` from `list1` using a calculation. I also checked for similar values using `set(list1) & set(list2)`

`list2` is actually a quadrant of `list1`, it is a follow up of [THIS QUESTION](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31403491/slicing-a-circle-in-equal-segments-python) I had asked previously. 
So from the above link you can see that I have RA and DEC co-ordinates of my data. In the example, assume `list1` is my RA.

So once I have my quandrants, I apply:

```
for a,b in zip(sliceno,list1):
    if a == 0:
        list2.append(a)
```

I know this is a follow-up of my previous question, so please bare with the complications!!

Comment: does your list have duplicate values I would rather try `len(set(list1))`

Comment: well, they are floats correct upto 13 decimal places, so I assume no

Comment: float comparison can be tricky at times, especially if the values from the two lists are results of calculations they might differ by ever so little and list2 is not a true subset of list1 but contains entries which are similar but not identical to entries in list1

Comment: Please show more of your code. What calculation produced `list2`?

Comment: @planetmaker: Do you think that if I decrease the decimal places to say 3 or 4 I may get the correct result?

Comment: Please add more information about your data and add some instance to your question!

Comment: What about the set difference? set(list1) - set(list2) ?, is length and content the same as new_list?

Comment: You can't "increase the decimal places". You need to take a big step back and understand how floating-point arithmetic works.

Comment: @Vixen: ok so here are the results. `len(set(list1)) = 13313` and `len(set(list2)) = 1747` and `len(set(list1) - set(list2)) = 11566`

Comment: So it seems like you have duplicates in both lists

Comment: @Vixen: Can I remove the duplicates or is there any other way to get my `new_list` ??

Comment: I believe the easiest way is to do just the set differance, since when you create a set it s automatically removes duplicates. If you need your result as a list, then just 'list(theSetDifferance)'

Comment: @Vixen: By set difference you mean: `new_list = [x for x in set(list1) if x not in set(list2)] `

Comment: `new list = set(list1) - set(list2)` should be the same as  `[x for x in set(list1) if x not in set(list2)]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is almost for sure that list2 has 11606 - 11584 = 22 repeated elements. (And because of list2 is a subset of list1 then they exist also in list1)

Comment: Is there a way I could remove the repeated elements, or any other alternative to get my `new_list` which will not contain the values of `list1` ??

Comment: `set(list1) - set(list2)`

Comment: Can you show the     `len(set(list2))` ?? If it is 1729 then the solution is clear,

Comment: Try to do the next:
    `list3 = set(list2)`
    `new_list = [x for x in list1 if x not in list3]`
And check your comprobations

Comment: ok so here are the results. `len(set(list1)) = 13313` and `len(set(list2)) = 1747 `and `len(set(list1) - set(list2)) = 11566`

Comment: `len(list1 - set(list2) = ? )`    Try that

Comment: You mean `len(list1) - len(set(list2))` right? That gives me 11610

Comment: new_list = [x for x in set(list1) if x not in set(list2)] try this and see the count

Comment: We are near to the solution, I think if it is 11610 is because of the difference between  1751 and 1747. So,  if you try your code again with this new set(list2), it should give you `len(new_list) = 11610`  (We hope)

Comment: @JuanManuelJiménez lets just keep hoping :P

Comment: @VigneshKalai: ஏன் பாஸ் கலாயிகறீங்க !!

Comment: @ThePredator tamilha theiyvama suma ulululva

Comment: @VigneshKalai: When I tried what you suggested, as @Juan points out, I get 22. So what does this mean? There are 22 similar values in `list1` that are present in `list2`??

Comment: Is it the following giving you 22(length of new_list)? `new_list = [x for x in set(list1) if x not in set(list2)]`

Comment: @ThePredator yes there are 22 duplicate value present in `list1` but they are not present in `list2`

Comment: @ThePredator france nu potu erunthigha

Comment: @VigneshKalai: Inga PhD panren boss. Inga discussion continue panna vendaam nu nenaikaren! Endha college neenga, illa enga work panreenga nu sollunga, Fb la add panren